# Mazes of Menace - a good map?

Tags: nethack

I have tried to make sense of the map at the following URL, but can not read it effectively:

http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Mazes_of_Menace

Is there an good map of the Mazes of Menace (Nethack) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree it is pretty hard to read, and I think is better explained in text.

You start on Dungeon Level 1.
At certain points in the game you can branch off to another area.

---

- You start at **Dungeon Level 1**, which is the top level of the **[Dungeons of Doom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Dungeons_of_Doom)**
- Somewhere between **Dungeon Level 2 - 4** you can branch off to the **[Gnomish Mines](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gnomish_Mines)**

  - On the 3rd or 4th level of the *[Gnomish Mines](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gnomish_Mines)* you will find **[Minetown](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Minetown)**
  - The last level of the *[Gnomish Mines](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gnomish_Mines)* is **[Mines' End](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Mines%27_End)**, which'll occur at the 8th or 9th level of the *[Gnomish Mines](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gnomish_Mines)*
- Somewhere between **Dungeon Level 5 - 9** you will find **[The Oracle](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/The_Oracle)**
- Just after *[The Orcle](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/The_Oracle)*, you can can branch off to **[Sokoban](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Sokoban)** *(which you'll actually enter from the bottom and is 4 stories high.)*
- There is a 40% change of a **[Big Room](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Big_Room)** somewhere between **Dungeon Level 10 - 12**
- Somewhere between **Dungeon Level 11 - 18** you can embark on a **[Quest](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Quest)**

  - The first Level of the *[Quest](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Quest)* will be the Quest Home Level.
  - The third Level of the *[Quest](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Quest)* will be a locate mission.
  - The last *[Quest](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Quest)* level, containing the Quest Goal is located somewhere between the 5th and 7th level of the *[Quest](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Quest)*
- Somewhere Between **Dungeon Level 10** and *[Medusa's Island](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Medusa%27s_Island)* you might be able to reach **[Fort Ludios](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Fort_Ludios)**
- Somewhere Between **Dungeon Level 15-18** you will find the **[Rogue level](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Rogue_level)**
- 1-4 levels before *[Castle](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Castle)* you will find **[Medusa's Island](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Medusa%27s_Island)**
- Somewhere Between **Dungeon Level 25-29** you will find the **[Castle](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Castle)**, which is also the last level of the *[Dungeons of Doom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Dungeons_of_Doom)*

---

- Right after the *[Castle](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Castle)*, you will enter the **[Valley of the Dead](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Valley_of_the_Dead)** which is also the first level of **[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)** (this will be **Dungeon Level 26-30**)
- The Lairs of three demons are located in *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)*:

  - **[Asmodeus' Lair](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Asmodeus%27_Lair)** is located somewhere between the 2nd and 7th levels of *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)*
  - **[Juiblex's swamp](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Juiblex%27s_swamp)** is located somewhere between the 4th and 7th levels of *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)*
  - **[Baalzebub's Lair](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Baalzebub%27s_Lair)** is located somewhere between the 6th and 9th levels of *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)*
- You can enter **[Vlad's Tower](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Vlad%27s_Tower)** from somewhere between the 9th and 13th levels of *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)*. *(you'll actually enter it from the bottom and it is 3 stories high.)*
- **[Orcus-town](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Orcus-town)** is located somewhere between the 10th and 15th levels of *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)*
- The **[Wizard's Tower](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wizard%27s_Tower)** is a set of three consecutive levels, which start somewhere between the 11th and 16th level of *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)* and have the last 2 levels lower.
- There are 2 **[Fake Wizard's Towers](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Fake_Wizard%27s_Towers)** levels, which are located between one to four levels above the *[Vibrating square](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Vibrating_square)*
- the level above *[Moloch's Sanctum](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Moloch%27s_Sanctum)* is **[Vibrating square](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Vibrating_square)**
- **[Moloch's Sanctum](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Moloch%27s_Sanctum)** is located somewhere between the 20th and 24th levels of *[Gehennom](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gehennom)* which translates back to somewhere between **Dungeon Level 45-53**. this is also the lowest level you can reach.

---

- The Negative levels are part of the **[End Game](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/End_Game)**, which consists of:

  - The four **[Elemental Planes](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Elemental_Planes)**:

    - The **[Plane of Earth](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Plane_of_Earth)**
    - The **[Plane of Air](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Plane_of_Air)**
    - The **[Plane of Fire](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Plane_of_Fire)**
    - The **[Plane of Water](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Plane_of_Water)**
  - The **[Astral Plane](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Astral_Plane)**, which is the location of your ultimate goal.

---

As you can see, due to it's complex design, and random generation, it is very difficult to produce a good map of the **[Mazes of Menace](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Mazes_of_Menace)**

*(All information has been collected from [Wikihack](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/))*